# Bullet Physics, CMake->CodeBlocks - MinGW: Doesn't find GL/glut.h?

Tags: build, cmake, mingw, glut, bulletphysics

Statistics...

My System: Windows Vista 64 bit

Library: Bullet Physics v2.78

Makefile Generator: CMake

Build system: MinGW command line, MinGW + CodeBlocks

Makefiles were implemented by command line and through CMake-generated Code::Blocks project

In both cases, the build fails near 30%. NOTE: I did have to switch the build executable in the Code::Blocks project from make.exe to mingw32-make.exe

First Failure: Demos\OpenGL\GLDebugFont.cpp -> GL/glut.h: No such file or directory

Second Failure (after commenting out the #include from the first) -> Demos/OpenGL/GlutStuff.h: same error

These failures happen when I build command-line OR through the generated C::B project.

Why can't it find GL/glut.h? "bullet-2.78\Glut\GL\glut.h" exists. Maybe there's a way I can tell it to find glut there?

NOTE: During the CMake makefile generation, CMake did tell me that "You are using the obsolete GLU package, please use OpenGL instead." It continued as normal with the Makefile generation. Maybe I need to define some environment variables? Maybe I need to configure something in Windows that CMake is looking for?

I would add a compiler search path in bullet-2.78/Glut, but Code::Blocks doesn't allow that if you're using a custom makefile (like a CMake-generated one).

UPDATE: I have been able to build the library itself, by building specific targets in the Code::Blocks project. However, I have been unable to build any of the demos or the benchmark test, since they all use OpenGL (and apparently glut.h). I would still like to compile those.